# Text isn't minimizing with screen HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, text, centering

I hope someone can help! When I minimize the browser screen on this code, everything is minimizing appropriately except for my body text. Not sure why this is happening! Can anybody find the issue in the HTML or CSS?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Ex Machina by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>History: Skating Today</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script src=
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/init.js">
    </script> <noscript>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
            .header {
    }
    </style></noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="page">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="page">
        <img alt="Black and white photo of boy skateboarding" height="" src=
        "images/OldTimey.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="unit header">
            <section>
                <header>
                    <h3>Unit 1: Skateboarding, Then and Now<br>
                    Lesson 1/3</h3>
                </header>
            </section>
        </div><!-- Main -->
        <div class="container" id="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="3u">
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4><a href="Index.html">Home</a></h4>
                    </section>
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4><a href="Programme%20Overview.html">Programme
                        Overview</a></h4>
                    </section>
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4><a href="Unit1.html">Unit 1: Skateboarding, Then
                        and Now</a></h4>
                        <ul class="style3">
                            <li><a href="History.html">Lesson 1: History of
                            Skateboarding</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Types.html">Lesson 2: Types of
                            Skating</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Quiz1.html">Unit 1 Quiz</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4><a href="Unit2.html">Unit 2: Why You Should
                        Skate</a></h4>
                        <ul class="style3">
                            <li><a href="EmotionalBenefits.html">Lesson 1:
                            Emotional and Physical Benefits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="SocialBenefits.html">Lesson 2: Social
                            and Enviromental Benefits (Plus a Few
                            More!)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Quiz2.html">Unit 2 Quiz</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4><a href = "Unit3.html">Unit 3: Safety & Upkeep</a></h4>
                        <ul class="style3">
                            <li><a href="SafePlace.html">Lesson 1: Determining Safe Places
                            to Skate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Stopping.html">Lesson 2: How to Stop a
                            Board</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Rules.html">Lesson 3: Rules of the
                            Road</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Bearings.html">Lesson 4: Changing Your Bearings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Trucks.html">Lesson 5: Adjusting Your Trucks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <h4>Extras: Skating Routes & Meet a Skater</h4>
                        <ul class="style3">
                            <li><a href="#">From the Flag Poles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">From the White Gates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">From the Pavilion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="MeetandGreet.html">Meet a Skater</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
               <div class= "9u skel-cell-important"">

                    <header>
                                <h3>Skating Today</h3>
                            </header>
                    <p> While some people may still see skaters as
                      rebellious or alternative, skateboarding has once
                      again evolved. In places like Afghanistan, where
                      girls are not allowed to ride bikes but can
                      skateboard, the sport is used to engage and empower
                      youth (skateistan.org). Furthermore, although many
                      skaters still take part in skateboarding to perfect
                      tricks and take risks, skateboarding has become the
                      way that many people get from point A to point B.</p>
<p></p>
                            <p>While any type of skateboard may be used for
                            transportation, the longboard is having its heyday.
                            A longboard can range anywhere from 33 to 80 inches
                            and typically has softer wheels, making for a
                            smoother and more stable ride, perfect for
                            cruising, less experienced, and older skaters
                            (Ruibal 2006).</p>
                            <img src="images/header.jpg" width="736" height="189" alt=""/><br>
                            <div id="course description">
                                <br>
                                <p>This lesson is now complete. To continue to lesson 2, "Types of Skating", click <a href=
                                "Types.html">next</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div><!-- Main -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@charset  "UTF-8";

/*
    Ex Machina by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
*/
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Basic                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/
body {
    background-image: url(../images/BackgroundImage.jpg);
}

body,input,textarea,select {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}


h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1b1b5e;
}

h4 
{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #1b1b5e;

}

/* Change this to whatever font weight/color pairing is most suitable */
strong,b {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}

em,i {
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Don't forget to set this to something that matches the design */
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

sub {
    position: relative;
    top: .5em;
    font-size: .8em;
}

sup {
    position: relative;
    top: -.5em;
    font-size: .8em;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}

blockquote {
    border-left: solid .5em #ddd;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    font-style: italic;
}

p,ul,ol,dl,table {
    margin-right: ;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    color: #1b1b5e;
}
tr. highlight td {
    padding: 2em;
}

header {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    color: #1b1b5e;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: left;
}

header h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
}


footer {
    margin-top: 1em;
}


/* Sections/Articles */


section,article {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.row
{
    padding: 0;
    position; center;
}


.intro {
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.aims {
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.unit header {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    color: purple;
}

table,th,td {
    border: ;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    align-content: center;
}

th,td {
    padding: 5px;
}

.boxed {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.formativequiz {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: ;
    text-align: left;
}

.formativequiz h1 {
    font: bold;
}

.formativequiz p {
    font: bold;
}

.question {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: ;
    width: 80%;
    background: #fff;
}

.question h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 40px;
    color: blue;
    font: bold;
}

.question h2:hover {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.question p {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .3s ease;
    -o-transition: color .3s ease;
    transition: color .3s ease;
}

h2:active ~ .yes {
    color: #1b1b5e;
    font-size: ;
}

.course description {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

#icons {
    height: 128;
    text-align: justify;
    border: none;
    font-size: .1px;
/* IE 9 & 10 don't like font-size: 0; */
    max-width: 888px;
}

#icons div {

    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    padding-right: 10%;

}

#icons:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
/* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Images */
.image {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em;
}

.image img {
    display: block ;
    width: ;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 2em;
}

.image.featured {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.image.full {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.image.left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2em .8em 0;
}

.image.centered {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 .8em;
}

.image.centered img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}



/* Lists */

ul.default {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.default li {
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 0 1.25em;
    border-top: 1px solid #303030;
}

ul.default li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: none;
}

ul.default a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

ul.default a:hover {
}

ul.style1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style1 li {
    padding: .6em 0;
}

ul.style1 li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}

ul.style1 img {
}

ul.style2 {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 2%;
    list-style: disc;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

ul.style2 li {
    padding: .5em 0 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

ul.style2 li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}

ul.style3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    font: 14px;
}

ul.style3 li {
    padding-left: .6em;
    line-height: 150%;
}

ul.style3 li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}

ul.style5 {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style5 li {
    float: left;
    padding: .25em;
    line-height: 0;
}

ul.style5 a {
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Header                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/



/*********************************************************************************/
/* Main                                                                          */
/*********************************************************************************/
#page {
    margin: 7em;
    position: center;
    background: #fff;
}

#main {
    padding: 1em;
}

#container {
    position: center;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}



/*********************************************************************************/
/* Icons                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/


.greenleaf {
    align-content: relative;
}

.trafficlight {
    align-content: relative;
}

.pinkskater {
}

.map {
}
```

Comment: No one wants to wade through your wall of code. Post a [mcve] and any errors you're getting.

Comment: Which units did you use for the text?

Answer (score 1):

Add media queries to your CSS to define you font sizes for various window sizes. Here's a simple example from [this post](http://zellwk.com/blog/responsive-typography/) (written in Sass):

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that in your css you set the font size of body in pixels. try changing it to em instead of px and it should adjust in size. But it's hard to tell with so much going on.